# blank_target in struts2

Tags: struts2

can any one suggest how to write target="_blank" in struts2. I  tried something like below but the hyperlink was not working

```
<s:url id="imageDownload" namespace="/" action="downloadImage" var="urlTag">
    <s:param name="ImageFileName" value="%{ImageFileName}"></s:param>
    <s:param name="id" value="%{id}"></s:param>
</s:url>

<a  class="linkView" href="<s:property value="#urlTag" />" target="_blank">
    <s:property value="ImageFileName" />
</a>
```

thanks

Comment: What you mean the "blank_target"?

Comment: i have image hyperlink and when clicked it should open a new window

Answer (score 0):

I think

```
<a  class="linkView" href="<s:property value="#urlTag" />" target="_blank">
   <s:property value="ImageFileName" />
</a>
```

is correct.